# Use Flex.SWC Symbols in a Customized ImageButtonSkin

Tags: flash, apache-flex, styles, symbols, skin

First, I have a skin `ImageButtonSkin.mxml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Skin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
        xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
    <!-- host component -->
    <fx:Metadata>
        [HostComponent("spark.components.Button")]
    </fx:Metadata>

    <!-- states -->
    <s:states>
        <s:State name="disabled" />
        <s:State name="down" />
        <s:State name="over" />
        <s:State name="up" />
    </s:states>

<!-- what should I use here????? BitmapImage might not be working for symbols from SWC lib -->
    <s:BitmapImage id="theImage"
             source.up="{getStyle('imageSkinUp')}"
             source.over="{getStyle('imageSkinOver')}"
             source.down="{getStyle('imageSkinDown')}"
             source.disabled="{getStyle('imageSkinDisabled')}" />

    <!-- SkinParts
    name=iconDisplay, type=spark.primitives.BitmapImage, required=false
    name=labelDisplay, type=spark.core.IDisplayText, required=false
    -->
</s:Skin>
```

Then I have a `ImageButton.as`:

```
package components
{
    import skins.ImageButtonSkin;

    import spark.components.Button;

    [Style(name="imageSkinUp", type="*")]
    [Style(name="imageSkinOver", type="*")]
    [Style(name="imageSkinDown", type="*")]
    [Style(name="imageSkinDisabled", type="*")]
    public class ImageButton extends Button
    {
        public function ImageButton()
        {
            super();
            setStyle("skinClass", ImageButtonSkin);
        }
    }
}
```

and I also have a `icons.swc` file exported from Flash CS5, and added to the build path.

Finally, I have the following in my `TestProject.mxml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600" xmlns:components="components.*">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            [Bindable]
            private var playing:Boolean = false;
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:Panel title="Test Project" width="400" height="300">
        <s:Button x="30" y="32" label="Button"
                  click="playing = !playing"
                  icon="{playing ? PLAY_ACTIVE : PLAY_ENABLED}" />

        <components:ImageButton x="19" y="96" label="ImageButton"
                                imageSkinUp="@Embed('assets/play.png')"
                                imageSkinOver="{PLAY_ACTIVE}"
                                imageSkinDown="{PLAY_ACTIVE}"
                                imageSkinDisabled="{PLAY_ACTIVE}" />
    </s:Panel>
</s:Application>
```

The problem is when I mouse over the `ImageButton`, the `PLAY_ACTIVE` symbol cannot be loaded from the swc file, while the `Button.icon` can use `PLAY_ACTIVE`.

(NOTE: the styling is working if I used `@Embed('assets/play.png')` for the `imageSkinUp` state).

So I'm asking if we could use swc symbols for the ButtonSkin? and if so, which container should I use for the swc symbols in `ImageButtonSkin.mxml`, `s:BitmapImage` or something else?

Answer (score 0):

It's not the swc that is the issue.  override public function styleChanged and call invalidateDisplayList() and override updateDisplayList as well and update you styles.  See this link for a full example of how that's done.

http://blogagic.com/98/styling-flex-custom-components

Comment: `PLAY_ACTIVE` from SWC symbol is working on the `Button`; `imageSkinUp="@Embed('assets/play.png')"` for the `ImageButton` is working.

Comment: ok, try this:  make your skin <s:SparkButtonSkin instead of <s:Skin and see if that makes a difference

Comment: No luck of using `s:SparkButtonSkin`. Which container should I use for the swc symbols in `ImageButtonSkin.mxml`, `s:BitmapImage` or something else?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my code was actually working.  I did not realize that the `PLAY_ACTIVE` symbol is white, so I did not see it.

The only thing not working is if the symbol has more than 1 frames, then the final result of the ImageButton can only display the first frame, no symbol animation (MovieClip in Flash).